# Вёрстка пропорциональных блоков

Tags: css, вёрстка

Как сверстать 3 блока в относительных величинах,
чтобы они имели одинаковые пропорции с 1920px до 1024px?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с flex-box:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  display:block;
  margin-top: 50%;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
}
.wrap-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
}
.wrap-right:before,
.wrap-right:after {
  content: '';
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.wrap-right:before {
  background-color: green;
}
.wrap-right:after {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="wrap-right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Зачем тут псевдоклассы?

Comment: @Vadizar, чтоб меньше лишних дивов было в разметке

Comment: Почему тогда в моих решениях нет лишних дивов и при этом   CSS  чистый?

Comment: @Vadizar, без понятия

Answer (score 3):

Добавлю ещё короткое решение через `flex`.  Флекс использовать лучше всего, на дворе 2018 год: ничего так гибко и интуитивно не настраивается как флекс. Например можно указать `min-height` у зелёного блока, и на определённом моменте ресайза окна он перестанет сужаться, а если размер контейнера ограничить по высоте - то что не влазит будет перескакивать из колонки в колонку.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 50vw;
}

.red {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

.green,
.blue {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="red">1</div>
  <div class="green">2</div>
  <div class="blue">3</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Это не то что хотел автор. Блоки не пропорциональны. Прочитайте вопрос хотя бы.

Comment: @Vadizar а, ну да проникся, добавил строчку.

Comment: Какой флекс? Сами же сказали, что на дворе 2018 - CSS Grid рулит!

Comment: @Vadizar согласен, вот, добавьте ответ, так сказать надо посвящать! Только вот grid уж больно смахивает на таблицу, я правда сказать не любитель сеток) Мне по догу службы раньше доставлались сайты с вёрсткой наполненной распрекрасными флоатами, абсолютами, псевдоэлементами, таблицами и прочими костылями: с этим счастьем совсем неприятно работать) Хорошо я больше по PHP :))

Answer (score 3):

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "box1 box2" "box1 box3";
}

#box1 {
  background-color: green;
  grid-area: box1;
}

#box2 {
  background-color: red;
  grid-area: box2;
}

#box3 {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-area: box3;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
<div id="box3"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с высотой от ширины (не зависит от ширины броузера):

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.ratio1_2:before {
  padding-top: 50%;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.boxes>div {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  color: #FFF
}

.boxes>div:nth-child(1) {
  background: blue;
}

.boxes>div:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}

.boxes>div:nth-child(3) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box">
    <div class='content'>Aspect ratio of 1:1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box ratio1_2">
    <div class='content'>Aspect ratio of 1:2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box ratio1_2">
    <div class='content'>Aspect ratio of 1:2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Идея [отсюда](http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html)

Comment: спасибо! Вариант с высотой от ширины подошел идеально

Comment: Какое-то костыльное решение.

Comment: @АлександрГруздев, отметьте ответ правильным, если вам он подошел

Comment: может и костыльное решение, но пропорции держит отлично. а с флексом не сложились медиа-запросы (большой блок пропадал когда запрос ставил ему width:100% или 100vw). особо не разбирался - использовал указанное решение

Answer (score -1):

#### 1. Самый простой вариант:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 25vw;
  float: left;
}
.red {
  height: 50vw;
  background: red;
}
.green {
  background: green;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
```

#### 2. Самый продвинутый вариант:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "a b"
                       "a d";
}
.red {
  grid-area: a;
  height: 50vw;
  background: red;
}
.green {
  background: green;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
   <div class="grid__item red">Grid Item 1</div>
   <div class="grid__item green">Grid Item 2</div>
   <div class="grid__item blue">Grid Item 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Работать то работает, но использование `float` сегодня, когда без него можно обойтись не меняя структуру, это ... Как и position впрочем)

Comment: какое-то кривое решение, а если отцентровынный сайт например в сетке бутстрепа?

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev использовать бутстрап - это само по себе костыльно. У меня представлено самое оптимальное решение, с нативными возможностями CSS. А вот у вас - явный костыль. Глупо это отрицать.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр предлагаешь везде без надобности совать флексбокс? Добавь на body overflow hidden, если тебя смущает неочищенный поток.

Comment: @Vadizar я везде использую флексбокс, где есть намёки на колонки, уже года 2, и ничуть не жалею! С этим удобно потом работать,  и заказчики не жалуются.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр но здесь флексбокс явно не требуется. Тем более вон один написал ответ - с флексбокс и псевдоэлемента. Зачем? Флексбокс нужно использовать, когда:

1. Без него не обойтись
2. На нем написать легче, быстрее и меньше на выходе кода.

По этим параметрам почему-то лишь мой ответ подходит.

Comment: @Vadizar кстати body у меня тоже flex - column , чтобы футер прилипал к низу без костылей с псевдоэлементами.

Comment: @Vadizar  да, на самом деле не очень, потому написал свой ответ :) Да флекс везде требуется, может быть block тут не требуется?

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр у вас ответ ниразу не подходит.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр но справедливости ради - ваш ответ лучше, чем с псевдожлементами. Доработайте только.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр а теперь посмотрите мой второй вариант.